# Reusing parts of TikZ animation in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, animations

I'd like to reuse part of an animated TikZ figure in `beamer`. Before switching to TikZ, I built PDF animations with IPE, and could select specific `page`s in the `\includegraphics{}` command. To do the same in TikZ, my approach would be to generate standalone tikz figures in PDFs and do the same as before. I'm wondering whether there is a more intelligent way that avoids the need for multiple files.

Note that the `\againframe{}` command won't help, since I want to have other content on the slide with the repeated animation as well.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
        \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    }}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{test}
        This is the first frame, which contains an animation:
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[rectangle](a){A}; 
            \node[rectangle,visible on=<2>] (b) at (0, 2) {B};
            \draw[->,visible on=<2>] (a) -- (b);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{test2}
        This is the second frame, which should include the figure from the 1st, 
        but only the final, i.e. second part of the animation.

        % ....?
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to refrain from the standalone approach? I have tried a couple of things in my life with beamer, but still find generating a multipage PDF from a standalone TiKZ figure to be included in a `foreach` loop with `includegraphics` (so that I can easily the number of animation steps, especially in `handout` mode) to be the most elegant and flexible approach.

Comment: I went for the standalone/beamer approach in the meantime, which is decent. The main issue I have with it is that the "slide" in the standalone has its own independent ordering (which can be slightly confusing, inconsistent) and it is not easy to make TikZ interact with surrounding text. Can you elaborate on how you combine `foreach` with `handout` mode?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to put your `tikzpicture` in a macro definition and call it multiple times:

```
\newcommand{\myanimation}{\begin{tikzpicture}...your code here}

\begin{frame}{test}
    This is the first frame, which contains an animation:
    \myanimation
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{test2}
    This is the second frame, which should include the figure from the 1st, 
    but only the final, i.e. second part of the animation.
    \myanimation
\end{frame}
```

This allows you to even introduce parameters so you can have slight variations in the second instance, say some captions change or you want different styles installed.

Another, less flexible, solution is to put your `tikzpicture` code into a `myanimation.tex` file and include it with `\input{myanimation}` when needed.

Note that both solutions are `beamer`-agnostic and will insert the full animation every time.

Comment: Your last sentence was the deal-breaker for that idea. Usually I don't want to reproduce a multi-step presentation completely, but a specific (usually the final) one (see original post)

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately my knowledge of beamer's internals is not good enough to bake a version of `\againframe` that only repeats a portion of a frame.
If anybody could, I would find it useful too.